# Python Append the data in multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas

when I run my code ,All the data appends in one long row.I would like to have  multiple rows
here is my code

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import date

path = r'C:\Users.....\Consumption Rate'
os.chdir(path)
os.getcwd()

files = os.listdir(path)
files

df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files:
    data = pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name= 'Charge summary',header=5, usecols="A:B",nrows=1)
    df = df.append(data)


for f in files:
    data = pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name= 'Charge summary',header=11, usecols="A:B",nrows=1)
    df = df.append(data)

for f in files:
    data = pd.read_excel(f,sheet_name= 'Charge summary',header=21, usecols="A:B",nrows=1)
    df = df.append(data)


df_new = df.rename(columns={'A': 'Col_1', 'C': 'Col_3'})
df_new.to_excel( 'Cement consumptions.xlsx', index = False)
```

I need to have 3 rows for this code instead of one row

Comment: What is the expected output and what are you getting now?

Comment: I am getting one line of output in one long row

Comment: I need to get one line per loop.All three rows

Comment: Do the header cells (`header=5/11/21`) contain the same column names (`'A'` and `'B'`)?

Comment: Headers(5/11/21) for all 3 loops are the different.

Comment: Headers(5/11/21) for all 3 loops are the different.The output is chain of rows similar to this:Micro 3243 32423 43656  Edison 45325  453454 43534  Macro 32432 324324 324324.I need them in 3 different row instead of one long row.There are 3 files with exactly same header and column number.Headers are Micro,Edison,Macro in all files.I am slicing specific row in each file using header and use column.